# Convert tweets.js to pandas dataframe , jupyter notebook

Tags: python, json, twitter, jupyter-notebook

[image]If you download an archive of all your tweets, Twitter sends you a zip file. This zip file, when unzipped contains several `.js` files.

One, is called `tweets.js`. tweets.js looks like a JSON file, but it's not exactly a JSON file. It has a strange key value that isn't a string, and the rest of the JSON file is in square brackets. The file also needs to be flattened

**How can i, using python, in a jupyter notebook, convert the `tweets.js` file into a pandas dataframe?**

(This is NOT using the API request. The file is loaded locally)

- tried using `pd.read_json()` didn't work
- tried removing the key, saving the file as `tweets.json`, save `json.dumps('tweets.json')` as a variable, use `flatten_json` to concert and save it as a new variable. it gives me an error message that it cannot read strings. Obviously because dumps returns a string

Comment: Can you share a sample of tweets.js ?

Comment: @Bushmaster yes, just added it